# Optimal Code Layout in Mathematica?

Tags: layout, wolfram-mathematica

I have now seen different elegant ways to layout code on this forum.

As a beginner, I would like to have your advises on the best way to layout code like the one below.

It is ugly,not optimal, probably even stupid, but may the expert programmers pardon me, I use it as a "worst case scenario".

The purpose for the novice I am is clarity.

```
rejection[disp_, fixationNOtoConsiderForDuration_, durationLimit_, 
 minDistance_] :=

With[{fakedata = consider[t4dataLAEH10, 9, disp, {17, 18, 11}]},

With[{num = 
 Flatten[Position[
   Take[fakedata[[All, 3]], fixationNOtoConsiderForDuration], 
   x_ /; (x > durationLimit)]]},

If[num =!= {},
With[{fakedata1 = Drop[fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]], Last@num]},
 With[{num1 =
    Flatten[Position[
      Table[     
       Sqrt[((fakedata1[[fixation1, 1]] - 
           centerX)^2 + (fakedata1[[fixation1, 2]] - 
           centerY)^2)],
       {fixation1, 1, Length@fakedata1}], 
      x_ /; (x < minDistance)]]},

  If[num1 =!= {},
   Delete[fakedata1[[All, {1, 2}]], List /@ num1], 
   fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]]]]],
With[{fakedata2 = fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]]},  
 With[{num2 =
    Flatten[Position[
      Table[       
       Sqrt[((fakedata2[[fixation2, 1]] - 
           centerX)^2 + (fakedata2[[fixation2, 2]] - 
           centerY)^2)],
       {fixation2, 1, Length@fakedata2}], 
      x_ /; (x < minDistance)]]},
  If[num2 =!= {},
   Delete[fakedata2[[All, {1, 2}]], List /@ num2], 
   fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]]]]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: The Wolfram Workbench has a Format option. Unfortunately there are no style checkers for Mathematica as there are for Java so no matter what you agree about style it is hard to enforce.

Style is a dangerous topic like Linux / Windows / Mac. Or Android / iOS. Whatever. You'll never agree. But you have to with your peers. But again, without style checkers any agreements on style won't last.

- To me the code above is not readable because it lacks commenting.

Comment: @ndroock1, thank you, I definitely have to add comment. Since I am into it 24h currently I don`t put some, put I will soon before I lose it.

Comment: It should be noted that the way code appears on Stackoverflow may differ quite a bit from the way it does in  our notebooks. I know I change my code often to cater for the restricted line length here. Also, in contrast to Brett, I do use 2D expressions all the time because it reduces the chance of typos in equations. That too,  doesn't translate to SO.

Comment: @Sjoerd, Thank you. Your layout is yet the one I use that indeed to avoid costly and yet regular mistakes.

Comment: The indentations and line breaks that you show (in the picture) look pretty good to me.  I prefer it so the many-hanging-brackets style of code for Mathematica, because I prefer to see more on a single screen.   What I find problematic is the sprawling function definition itself, the redundancy of code, and the lack of any comments or descriptions.  I do not have time right now, but later I will refactor this code as I would write it.  Of course, I'll have to guess a bit about the comments/descriptions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, whenever I have the time, I shall revamp this code with the solutions on finding Vector Norm with an arbitrary Origin, I believe a lot of redundancy comes from this. And I actually believe I could tune you conditional operation code to fit this. But I now only use things I understand well, and I believe I have made progress enough to realize I am not comfortable yet with your some of your compact ones. But just not YET ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I chose to do a full rewrite because the original is simply too far from my own style for me to format it as I would my own code.

I did not attempt to test this, so it is entirely possible something is broken, but I believe that most of it is correct.

I use Text Cells to describe the syntax of my functions.  I typically embed `(* comments *)` to explain the code, but if the explanations become very long, I move them to Text Cells as well.

I included a comment explaining `func1`.  It is not a very helpful comment, but it serves as an example.

Here is an image of my notebook at 75% magnification:

[image]

Cell expression for copy&paste:

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell["Rewrite", "Subsection"],

Cell[TextData[{
 StyleBox["distance", "Program"],
 "[{",
 StyleBox["x1",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 ", ",
 StyleBox["y1",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 "}] gives EuclideanDistance from {x1, y1} to global {centerX, \
centerY}\n",
 StyleBox["distance", "Program"],
 "[{",
 StyleBox["x1",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 ", ",
 StyleBox["y1",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 "}, {",
 StyleBox["x2",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 ", ",
 StyleBox["y2",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 "}] gives EuclideanDistance from {x1, y1} to {x2, y2}"
}], "Text"],

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"distance", "[", 
   RowBox[{"a_", ",", 
    RowBox[{"b_:", 
     RowBox[{"Hold", "@", 
      RowBox[{"{", 
       RowBox[{"centerX", ",", "centerY"}], "}"}]}]}]}], "]"}], ":=", 
  RowBox[{"EuclideanDistance", "[", 
   RowBox[{"a", ",", 
    RowBox[{"ReleaseHold", "@", "b"}]}], "]"}]}]], "Input"],

Cell[TextData[{
 StyleBox["rejection", "Program"],
 "[",
 StyleBox["disp, fixation, durationLimit, minDistance",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 "]\n\nfilters data from ",
 StyleBox["t4dataLAEH10", "Program"],
 " according to:\n\t",
 StyleBox["disp",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 " : (description of argument disp)\n\t",
 StyleBox["fixation",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 " : (description of argument fixation)\n\t",
 StyleBox["durationLimit",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 " : (description of durationLimit)\n\t",
 StyleBox["minDistance",
  FontSlant->"Italic"],
 " : (description of minDistance)"
}], "Text"],

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"rejection", "[", 
   RowBox[{
   "disp_", ",", "fixation_", ",", "durationLimit_", ",", 
    "minDistance_"}], "]"}], ":=", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
  RowBox[{"Module", "[", 
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"{", 
     RowBox[{"fakedata", ",", "num", ",", "func1"}], "}"}], ",", 
    "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
    RowBox[{"(*", " ", 
     RowBox[{"description", " ", "of", " ", "fakedata"}], " ", "*)"}],
     "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
    RowBox[{
     RowBox[{"fakedata", "=", 
      RowBox[{"consider", "[", 
       RowBox[{"t4dataLAEH10", ",", "9", ",", "disp", ",", 
        RowBox[{"{", 
         RowBox[{"17", ",", "18", ",", "11"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]}], ";", 
     "\[IndentingNewLine]", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
     RowBox[{"(*", " ", 
      RowBox[{"description", " ", "of", " ", "num"}], " ", "*)"}], 
     "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
     RowBox[{"num", "=", 
      RowBox[{"Position", "[", 
       RowBox[{
        RowBox[{
         RowBox[{"fakedata", "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", 
          RowBox[{"All", ",", "3"}], "\[RightDoubleBracket]"}], "~", 
         "Take", "~", "fixation"}], ",", 
        RowBox[{"x_", "/;", 
         RowBox[{"x", ">", "durationLimit"}]}]}], "]"}]}], ";", 
     "\[IndentingNewLine]", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
     RowBox[{"(*", " ", 
      RowBox[{
       RowBox[{"func1", ":", " ", 
        RowBox[{
        "Take", " ", "the", " ", "first", " ", "two", " ", "columns", 
         " ", "of", " ", "fakedata"}]}], ",", " ", 
       RowBox[{
        RowBox[{
         RowBox[{
         "and", " ", "drop", " ", "rows", " ", "specified", " ", "by",
           " ", 
          RowBox[{
           StyleBox["dropspec",
            FontSlant->"Italic"], ".", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
           "Delete"}], " ", "any", " ", "rows", " ", "for", " ", 
          "which", " ", 
          StyleBox["distance", "Program"]}], " ", "<", " ", 
         StyleBox["minDistance",
          FontSlant->"Italic"]}], ";", " ", 
        RowBox[{
        "if", " ", "no", " ", "rows", " ", "are", " ", "deleted"}]}], 
       ",", "\[IndentingNewLine]", "   ", 
       RowBox[{
       "return", " ", "the", " ", "first", " ", "two", " ", "columns",
         " ", "of", " ", "fakedata"}], ",", " ", 
       RowBox[{"ignoring", " ", 
        RowBox[{"dropspec", "."}]}]}], 
      StyleBox[" ",
       FontSlant->"Italic"], "*)"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
     RowBox[{
      RowBox[{"func1", "[", "dropspec_", "]"}], ":=", 
      RowBox[{"Module", "[", 
       RowBox[{
        RowBox[{"{", 
         RowBox[{"part", ",", "fake"}], "}"}], ",", 
        "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
        RowBox[{
         RowBox[{"part", "=", 
          RowBox[{"fakedata", "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", 
           RowBox[{"All", ",", 
            RowBox[{"{", 
             RowBox[{"1", ",", "2"}], "}"}]}], 
           "\[RightDoubleBracket]"}]}], ";", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
         RowBox[{"fake", "=", 
          RowBox[{"part", "~", "Drop", "~", "dropspec"}]}], ";", 
         "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
         RowBox[{
          RowBox[{
           RowBox[{"If", "[", 
            RowBox[{
             RowBox[{"#", "=!=", 
              RowBox[{"{", "}"}]}], ",", 
             RowBox[{"fake", "~", "Delete", "~", "#"}], ",", "part"}],
             "]"}], "&"}], "@", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
          RowBox[{"Position", "[", 
           RowBox[{
            RowBox[{"distance", "/@", "fake"}], ",", 
            RowBox[{"x_", "/;", 
             RowBox[{"x", "<", "minDistance"}]}]}], "]"}]}]}]}], 
       "]"}]}], ";", "\[IndentingNewLine]", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
     RowBox[{"If", "[", 
      RowBox[{
       RowBox[{"num", "=!=", 
        RowBox[{"{", "}"}]}], ",", 
       RowBox[{"func1", " ", "@", " ", 
        RowBox[{"num", "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", 
         RowBox[{
          RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ",", "1"}], "\[RightDoubleBracket]"}]}],
        ",", 
       RowBox[{"func1", "@", "0"}]}], "]"}]}]}], " ", 
   "]"}]}]], "Input"]
}, Open  ]]
```

Comment: by the way, if `fixation` is a positive integer, you could use: `num = Position[fakedata[[;; fixation, 3]], x_ /; x > durationLimit];`

Comment: Thanks ! How did you print that "Cell expressions for copy & paste" ? And by the way, it almost works, despite you coded that "blindly". There is a tiny bug with values that don`t get deleted but as soon as I can I`ll tackle that !

Comment: @500 Right-click on cell bracket, `Copy As` `>` `Cell Expression`; or, select the block, and menu `Edit` `>` `Copy As` `>` `Cell Expression`.  I am glad it mostly worked.  What is the bug? (email me if you care to)

Comment: , Thank You, I have revamped the function I used, I think You`ll like it ! I will send you my .nb soon hopefully !

Answer (score 5):

- In the case of your code above, I'd split the `Flatten[Position[...]]` out into a separate function.
- I'd also use a single scoping construct instead of a nested `With`.

like:

```
Block[{fakedata, fakedata1, fakedata2, num, result},
  fakedata = ...;
  num = ...;

  If[num =!= {},
    fakedata1 = ...;
    result = localPoints[fakedata1];
    ];

  num1 = ...;
  If[num1 =!= {},
    fakedata2 = ...;
    result = localPoints[fakedata2];
    ];

  result
  ]
```

- I don't like to use typesetting (subscripts, superscripts, square roots, etc...) in code, since for me that tends to be a text environment (whether it's Workbench, or email, or on the web, ...)  Anywhere else, it's fair game.

Comment: (Not related to code formatting, but seems appropriate to ask here, given the topic.) I've long wondered if WRI has any internal documents/guidelines specific to the design of packages that extend Mathematica, using Mathematica. Why? Software design/planning in Mathematica doesn't seem to be covered anywhere in the wild---docs really only show the features of the language and how to code using many different styles/paradigms. Can you shed some light on how things work on the inside? Sometimes I get the sense that the only people who REALLY know how to DESIGN in MMA are in WRI.

Answer (score 3):

I have a saying, "don't be clever", meaning prefer clarity of code above other priorities when possible.  Some day someone will revisit this code and he or she will appreciate knowing what the code is doing.  This is related to formatting (format for clarity), but also nesting of function calls.  It's easy to write very nested incomprehensible code in Mathematica.  To keep things clear, I tend to use temporary or intermediate variables and break my long, nested function calls into little meaningful chunks.  Even if you reuse the variable, it's much easier to follow the steps or insert Print[]'s in there to see what's going on at each step.  Helper functions are good too.

From a formatting standpoint, I tend to format like this:

```
   If[test, 
        expr1, 
   (* ELSE *)
        expr2
    ]
```

My previous comments mean that I tend to have multiple lines instead of lots of long nested things which makes also makes formatting simpler.  Try to keep expr1 / expr2 to less than about 80 chars.  I think that's a reasonable length and decent test if it's getting too long.  These are just guidelines, and can and should be broken at times, but I think they're helpful and hope you find them helpful too.

*** UPDATE ***

This is how I would purely format this code.... Note the rather long lines...

```
rejection[disp_, fixationNOtoConsiderForDuration_, durationLimit_, minDistance_] :=    
With[{fakedata = consider[t4dataLAEH10, 9, disp, {17, 18, 11}]},
    With[{num = Flatten[Position[Take[fakedata[[All, 3]], fixationNOtoConsiderForDuration], x_ /; (x > durationLimit)]]},

        If[num =!= {},
            With[{fakedata1 = Drop[fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]], Last@num]},
                With[{num1 = Flatten[Position[Table[Sqrt[((fakedata1[[fixation1, 1]] - centerX)^2 + (fakedata1[[fixation1, 2]] - centerY)^2)], {fixation1, 1, Length@fakedata1}], x_ /; (x < minDistance)]]},
                    If[num1 =!= {},
                        Delete[fakedata1[[All, {1, 2}]], List /@ num1],
                    (* ELSE *) 
                        fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        (* ELSE *)
            With[{fakedata2 = fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]]},  
                With[{num2 = Flatten[Position[Table[Sqrt[((fakedata2[[fixation2, 1]] - centerX)^2 + (fakedata2[[fixation2, 2]] - centerY)^2)], {fixation2, 1, Length@fakedata2}], x_ /; (x < minDistance)]]},
                    If[num2 =!= {},
                        Delete[fakedata2[[All, {1, 2}]], List /@ num2],
                    (* ELSE *) 
                        fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

More involved refactoring:

```
(* Try to put types on these variables. It'll be easier to identify what's going in *)
rejection[disp_, fixationNOtoConsiderForDuration_, durationLimit_, minDistance_] := 
Module[{fakedata, num1, fakedata1, num, fakedata2, num2},
    fakedata = consider[t4dataLAEH10, 9, disp, {17, 18, 11}];
    num = Flatten[Position[Take[fakedata[[All, 3]], fixationNOtoConsiderForDuration], x_ /; (x > durationLimit)]];
    If[num =!= {}, 
        fakedata1 = Drop[fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]], Last@num];
        num1 = Table[Sqrt[((fakedata1[[fixation1, 1]] - centerX)^2 + (fakedata1[[fixation1, 2]] - centerY)^2)], {fixation1, 1, Length@fakedata1}];
        num1 = Flatten[Position[num1, x_ /; (x < minDistance)]];
        If[num1 =!= {},
            Delete[fakedata1[[All, {1, 2}]], List /@ num1],
        (* ELSE *) 
            fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]]
        ], 
    (* ELSE *)
        fakedata2 = fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]];
        num2 = Table[Sqrt[((fakedata2[[fixation2, 1]] - centerX)^2 + (fakedata2[[fixation2, 2]] - centerY)^2)], {fixation2, 1, Length@fakedata2}];
        num2 = Flatten[Position[num2, x_ /; (x < minDistance)]];
        If[num2 =!= {},
            Delete[fakedata2[[All, {1, 2}]], List /@ num2],
        (* ELSE *) 
            fakedata[[All, {1, 2}]]
        ]           
    ]
]
```

There are more variables here than necessary, and I'm not happy with the num1/2=Table[] line. It's still a long and I'd probably either try to make a helper function out of it or use Normal[] which seems similar to what this code is trying to do.

Comment: Keeping `expr` to less than 80 chars is pretty difficult. See `Histogram@Select[StringLength@# & /@ Names["*"], # > 1 &]`

Comment: Thank You for the Demo, it helps a lot,I shall redo this code to integrate solution on computing vectro norm on an arbitrary origin very soon !

Comment: would you know why sometimes, despite using fixed width font, things can`t align as ones will ?